# Why when I modify a linked list inside a function am I getting a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have written a helper function that was designed to add a node to a linked list. The location this was to be done with the following segment.

```
tcb_add(running,temp);
```

This segment is supposed to add temp to running. Here is my code for the function.

```
void tcb_add(tcb_t *first, tcb_t *second) { //fix
  if (first == NULL) {
    first = second;
  } else {
    while (first->next != NULL) {
      first = first->next;
    }
    first->next = second;
  }
}
```

If instead of using the line `tcb_add(running,temp);` I just say `running = temp` it works. But for other parts of my code, I would like to have the function since it was only that easy since `temp` was the first node being added. Any help would be very appreciated.

There is, of course, more code but I believe I isolated the problem.

Here is the output from Valgrind when I call `tcb_add(running,temp);`, but keep in mind when I instead say `running = temp` the segment works.

```
==30628== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==30628== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==30628== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==30628== Command: ./test00
==30628==
==30628== Invalid read of size 8
==30628==    at 0x400930: t_create (t_lib.c:42)
==30628==    by 0x4007F9: main (test00.c:25)
==30628==  Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==30628==
==30628==
==30628== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==30628==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x8
==30628==    at 0x400930: t_create (t_lib.c:42)
==30628==    by 0x4007F9: main (test00.c:25)
==30628==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==30628==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==30628==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==30628==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==30628==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==30628==
==30628== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30628==     in use at exit: 67,432 bytes in 4 blocks
==30628==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 0 frees, 67,432 bytes allocated
==30628==
==30628== LEAK SUMMARY:
==30628==    definitely lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==30628==    indirectly lost: 936 bytes in 1 blocks
==30628==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30628==    still reachable: 66,472 bytes in 2 blocks
==30628==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30628== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==30628==
==30628== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==30628== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

### Edit

The variable running is defined as follows:

```
tcb_t *running;
tcb_t *ready;
```

This is according to the struct:

```
struct tcb_t {
    int         thread_id;
    int         thread_priority;
    ucontext_t *thread_context;
    struct tcb_t *next;
}; typedef struct tcb_t tcb_t;
```

As asked this is my t_create function:

```
int t_create(void (*fct)(int), int id, int pri) {
  size_t sz = 0x10000;
  ucontext_t *uc;
  uc = (ucontext_t *)malloc(sizeof(ucontext_t));

  getcontext(uc);
  uc->uc_stack.ss_sp = malloc(sz); /* new statement */
  uc->uc_stack.ss_size = sz;
  uc->uc_stack.ss_flags = 0;
  uc->uc_link = running->thread_context;

  makecontext(uc, (void (*)(void))fct, 1, id);
  tcb_t *new_tcb = malloc(sizeof(tcb_t));
  new_tcb->thread_context = uc;
  new_tcb->thread_id = id;
  new_tcb->thread_priority = pri;
  new_tcb->next = NULL;
  tcb_t *tmp = ready;
  if (tmp == NULL) // I would like to replace this portion with tcb_add()
    ready = new_tcb;
  else {
    while (tmp->next != NULL) {
      tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmp->next = new_tcb;// To here
  }
```

Also to further explain although the valgrind report mentions t_create this is where I believed the problem took place.

```
void t_init() {
  tcb_t *temp = tcb_create();
    temp->thread_context = (ucontext_t *) malloc(sizeof(ucontext_t));
    temp->thread_id = 0;
    temp->thread_priority = 0;
    temp->next = NULL;

    getcontext(temp->thread_context);

    tcb_add(running,temp); //DOES NOT WORK
  //running = temp;        //WORKS
  ready = NULL;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `running ` before you call `tcb_add(running, temp)`?

Comment: Your Valgrind log says you dereferenced a null pointer, and log points towards `t_create (t_lib.c:42)`. What is there?

Comment: @RayToal running has no value it is just initialized. temp is given a value then assigned to running, or should be. Does that answer your question? Please look at the edits I made.

Comment: @milleniumbug This confused me too but the call of `tcb_add()` was not in `t_create()`, and when I replaced it with `running = temp` it worked. This was in `t_itit()`, would it help if I added that? Check the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If instead of using the line `tcb_add(running,temp);` I just say `running = temp` it works

`running` is passed by value. Therefore the function has no way of modifying it. You have to pass a pointer to pointer.

```
void tcb_add(tcb_t **first, tcb_t *second) { //fix
  if (*first == NULL) {
    *first = second;
  } else {
    while ((*first)->next != NULL) {
      *first = (*first)->next;
    }
    (*first)->next = second;
  }
}

// ...

tcb_add(&running,temp);
```

To elaborate:

```
void f(int x) { x = 42; }

int x = 23;
f(x);
printf("%d\n", x); // WILL PRINT 23
```

in your case, the variable never changed, and kept the original `NULL` value.

Comment: How would I do this? My function declaration is above.

Comment: Oops, you already updated it :) let me try.

Comment: Lovely! This works! Not sure why Valgrind gave the error it gave but none the less haha thank you!

Comment: @AnthonySette See the update. Hopefully this short code example explains better. Also, this http://c-faq.com/stdio/fopenfp.html

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you! Wish I could upvote twice!